# Xpath - Retrieveing Text value when condition contains a tag

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

I have section of a table and I am trying to get the value "Distributor 10"

```
<table class="d">
    <tr>
        <td class="ah">supplier<td>
        <td class="ad">
            <a href="/S/3/143.html">Supplier 10</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ah">distributor<pre><td>
        <td class="ad">
            <a href="/D/3/143.html">Distributor 10</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I am within Chrome Developer, I get this value by using the following xpath string

```
//tr/td[text()="distributor]/following-sibling::td[@class="ad"]/a/text()
```

But when I code this in python - it returns an empty list... From what I can see its is because of the `<pre>` tag next to "distributor"
When I amend the above mentioned xpath to look for ***"supplier"*** instead of ***distributor*** it works perfectly well

any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Please add python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using lxml you can use one of the following XPath to get this working :

```
//tr[contains(.,"distributor")]//a/text()

//a[parent::td[@class="ad"] and starts-with(@href,"/D")]/text()
```

Piece of code :

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
html = '''<table class="d">
    <tr>
        <td class="ah">supplier<td>
        <td class="ad">
            <a href="/S/3/143.html">Supplier 10</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ah">distributor<pre><td>
        <td class="ad">
            <a href="/D/3/143.html">Distributor 10</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>'''

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser)

data = tree.xpath('//tr[contains(.,"distributor")]//a/text()')
print (data)
```

Output : `['Distributor 10']`

Alternative : use lxml html cleaner class ("remove_tags") to remove the pre element from your page.

References :

- https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html
- https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html

Comment: Thank you E.Wiest - I should have thought a the contains function! Still new at xPath